# Sending email attachment using SmtpClient in ASP.NET Core 3.1 giving "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 and I have to send files as an email attachment using SmtpClent using the below code.

I want to store the posted files to an **Attachments** property in Message.cs class and I want to pass this class to SendEmail method. When I send email using EmailSender class's **SendEmail** method, I do receive "Cannot access a closed Stream." I think I am making mistake to put values to the Attachments property of the Message.cs. Could you please help me on how to do this correctly?

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    var files = Request.Form.Files.Any() ? Request.Form.Files : new FormFileCollection();
   
    List<string> recipients = new List<string>
        { "abc@gmail.com",
            "xyz@gmail.com"};

   _emailSender.SendEmail(new Message(recipients, "Test Subject", "<h1>Welcome</h2>", files));

    
    return View();
}
```

**Message.cs**

```
public class Message
    {
        public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public Message(IEnumerable<string> to, string subject, string content, IFormFileCollection attachments)
        {
            Recipients = new List<string>();
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

            Recipients.AddRange(to.Select(x => x));
            Subject = subject;
            Content = content;
            foreach(var file in attachments)
            {
                Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName));
            }            
        }
    }
```

**EmailSender.cs**

```
   public class EmailSender
    {
        public void SendEmail(Message message)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                SendMailAsync(message);
            });
        }

    private async void SendMailAsync(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
                mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mailMessage.Body = message.Content;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("From email");
                foreach (var recipient in message.Recipients)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
                }

                if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                }

                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("Host name", 587))
                {
                    NetworkCredential smtpUserInfo = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");

                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = smtpUserInfo;
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendMailAsync exception: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendMailAsync done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: files get disposed after request ends, await for your async method, or copy them to MemoryStream

Comment: @YegorAndrosov I have to present the success page immediately to the user and if I await it takes time to complete. So I want to copy the files to  Attachments property and want to achieve this without await.

Comment: then you might use second option, copy files to MemoryStream before starting your async request, this way they won't get disposed

Answer (score 1):

Copy your files to `MemoryStream`s, so they don't go out of scope when request ends

```
var files = Request.Form.Files.Any() ? Request.Form.Files : new FormFileCollection();

var filesInStreams = files.Select(x =>
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    x.CopyTo(ms);
    return (ms, x.FileName);
}).ToList();

_emailSender.SendEmail(new Message(recipients, "Test Subject", "<h1>Welcome</h2>", filesInStreams));
```

You will need to adjust `Message` constructor as well

```
public class Message
{
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public Message(IEnumerable<string> to, string subject, string content, List<(Stream stream, string fileName)> attachments)
    {
        Recipients = new List<string>();
        Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

        Recipients.AddRange(to.Select(x => x));
        Subject = subject;
        Content = content;
        foreach (var file in attachments)
        {
            Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.stream, file.fileName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I have changed Stream to MemoryStream in the Message class constructor List<(MemoryStream stream, string fileName)> attachments to compile the code.  When I use the code, the files are attached with the email without any contents on it (empty files). Do you know what is happening?